# Vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the set $S$ of tuples $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $a_2$ is rational. Is this a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

My response is that it isn't because a scalar multiple of $v = (a_1, \dots ,a_n)$ by $k \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ puts $kv$ outside of $S$ given that $k a_2$ is irrational. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, any irrational multiple of a tuple in $S$ will not be in $S$. Therefore, not closed under scalar multiplication, and so not a subspace.